# Android widget with 3 buttons. And different intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I have a strange issue with a Widget that I am trying to create.
The widget is a random question with 3 answer options (buttons).
I load the question from the internet and that works.

I mix up the answers, so the answer is not always in the same location.
Also, it is possible to have multiple correct answers.

```
public RemoteViews setAnswers(JSONObject questionObj, RemoteViews views) throws JSONException {
    // Get the Answers
    String answerA = questionObj.getString("Ans1");
    String answerB = questionObj.getString("Ans2");
    String answerC = questionObj.getString("Ans3");

    // Get the Answers that is correct (1 = Correct, 0 = Wrong)
    int correctA = Integer.parseInt(questionObj.getString("correct1"));
    int correctB = Integer.parseInt(questionObj.getString("correct2"));
    int correctC = Integer.parseInt(questionObj.getString("correct3"));

    // Get help text for correct or wrong answer (HTML)
    String HTTPcor = questionObj.getString("HTTPcor")+" - Correct";
    String HTTPwro = questionObj.getString("HTTPwro")+" - Wrong";

    // Create the Intent for the answers that is correct
    Intent correctIntent = new Intent(maincontext, AdMain.class);
    correctIntent.putExtra("appWidID", appWidId);
    correctIntent.putExtra("correct", 1); // Answer is correct.
    correctIntent.putExtra("HTTP", HTTPcor); // Help text.
    PendingIntent correctIntentPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(maincontext, 0, correctIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Create the Intent for the answers that is wrong
    Intent wrongIntent = new Intent(maincontext, AdMain.class);
    wrongIntent.putExtra("appWidID", appWidId);
    wrongIntent.putExtra("correct", 0); // Answer is wrong.
    wrongIntent.putExtra("HTTP", HTTPwro); // Help text.
    PendingIntent wrongIntentPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(maincontext, 0, wrongIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Create a random number between 1 and 6 (6 different ways to mix up 3 buttons)
    Random generator = new Random();
    int mix = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
    Log.v("JapanWidget", "AnswerMix - "+mix+" - appWidId = "+appWidId);

    // DEBUG Set mix to 1 Until i get the Intent fixed.
    mix = 1;

    // Mix the buttons.
    switch(mix) {
      case 1:
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.Answer1, answerA); // Button 1 answer A
          // If correctA = 1 THEN set correctIntentPending ELSE set wrongIntentPending
          if (correctA == 1) { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer1, correctIntentPending); } else { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer1, wrongIntentPending); }
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.Answer2, answerB); // Button 2 answer B
          // If correctB = 1 THEN set correctIntentPending ELSE set wrongIntentPending
          if (correctB == 1) { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer2, correctIntentPending); } else { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer2, wrongIntentPending); }
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.Answer3, answerC); // Button 3 answer C
          // If correctB = 1 THEN set correctIntentPending ELSE set wrongIntentPending
          if (correctC == 1) { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer3, correctIntentPending); } else { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer3, wrongIntentPending); }
          break;
      default:  
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.Answer1, answerA);
          if (correctA == 1) { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer1, correctIntentPending); } else { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer1, wrongIntentPending); }
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.Answer2, answerB);
          if (correctB == 1) { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer2, correctIntentPending); } else { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer2, wrongIntentPending); }
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.Answer3, answerC);
          if (correctC == 1) { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer3, correctIntentPending); } else { views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Answer3, wrongIntentPending); }
          break;
    }

    return views;
}
```

The problem is, that when i do GetExtra from the new Activity, then it will always be the the extra that is set in the wrongIntentPending. Someting is going wrong here. But I do see that the "if (correctA == 1) {  } else {  }" works correct.
Even if I set it to "if (correctA == 1) {  } else {  }", then I get the Extra from the wrongIntentPending.

What is going wrong? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue, after reading this page: http://www.bogdanirimia.ro/android-widget-click-event-multiple-instances/269

**Working code:**

```
// Create the Intent for the answers that is correct
Intent correctIntent = new Intent(maincontext, AdMain.class);
correctIntent.putExtra("appWidID", appWidId);
correctIntent.putExtra("correct", 1); // Answer is correct.
correctIntent.putExtra("HTTP", HTTPcor); // Help text.
PendingIntent correctIntentPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(maincontext, 0, correctIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Create the Intent for the answers that is wrong
Intent wrongIntent = new Intent(maincontext, AdMain.class);
wrongIntent.putExtra("appWidID", appWidId);
wrongIntent.putExtra("correct", 0); // Answer is wrong.
wrongIntent.putExtra("HTTP", HTTPwro); // Help text.
PendingIntent wrongIntentPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(maincontext, 1, wrongIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

In the "PendingIntent getActivity (Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)" i needed to set 2 different requestCodes. Even is the google developer pages say that it is not currently used.

- context: The Context in which this PendingIntent should start the
  activity.
- requestCode: Private request code for the sender (currently
  not used).
- intent: Intent of the activity to be launched.
- flags: May be FLAG_ONE_SHOT, FLAG_NO_CREATE, FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT,
  FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, or any of the flags as supported by
  Intent.fillIn() to control which unspecified parts of the intent that
  can be supplied when the actual send happens.

So I changed this line:

PendingIntent wrongIntentPending = PendingIntent.getActivity(maincontext, **1**, wrongIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

And now it works.